# PHP Search Array Speed

Tags: php, arrays, performance, search

I would like to apologize in advance for the long post but I wanted to give you a clear picture of my problem. Any help is appreciated.

I have an array called **$data** with the following format:

[image]

...
...

Given an arbitrary start date, I need to search the array for matching dates:

```
//$holidays is an array with dates of public holidays which are not considered business days
$search_results = array();
$minDate = -10;
$maxDate = 100;
$start_date = "2015-02-25";

echo "Before loop: " . xdebug_time_index() . "<br>";

for ($i=$minDate; $i<=$maxDate; $i++) {
    if (in_array_r(getBusinessDay(new DateTime($start_date), $holidays, $i), $data)){
        $a_date = getBusinessDay(new DateTime($start_date), $holidays, $i);
        $a_key = array_search($a_date, array_column($data, "date"));
        $search_results[]=array($i, $data[$a_key]["data"]);
    }
}

echo "After loop: " . xdebug_time_index() . "<br>";

var_dump($search_results);
```

However, this code snippet, which might run 10-15 times as the page loads, takes a long time to execute (at least 6 seconds on bigger arrays) each turn:

[image]

**Could you please help me understand which part of code is causing this delay and how could I possibly speed up this process?**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here are the functions used in the code snippet:

```
function getBusinessDay($startdate, $holidays, $days) {

    $calculator = new BusinessDaysCalculator($startdate, $holidays, [BusinessDaysCalculator::SATURDAY, BusinessDaysCalculator::SUNDAY]);
    $calculator->addBusinessDays($days);
    $result = $calculator->getDate()->format('Y-m-d');
    unset($calculator);

    return $result;
}

function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the calculator which returns the next business day (skips weekends and any dates in the $holidays array):

```
class BusinessDaysCalculator {

    const MONDAY    = 1;
    const TUESDAY   = 2;
    const WEDNESDAY = 3;
    const THURSDAY  = 4;
    const FRIDAY    = 5;
    const SATURDAY  = 6;
    const SUNDAY    = 7;

    /**
     * @param DateTime   $startDate       Date to start calculations from
     * @param DateTime[] $holidays        Array of holidays, holidays are no considered business days.
     * @param int[]      $nonBusinessDays Array of days of the week which are not business days.
     */
    public function __construct(DateTime $startDate, array $holidays, array $nonBusinessDays) {
        $this->date = $startDate;
        $this->holidays = $holidays;
        $this->nonBusinessDays = $nonBusinessDays;
    }

    public function addBusinessDays($howManyDays) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < abs($howManyDays)) {
            if ($howManyDays < 0) {
                $this->date->modify("-1 day");
            } else {
                $this->date->modify("+1 day");
            }
            if ($this->isBusinessDay($this->date)) {
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public function getDate() {
        return $this->date;
    }

    private function isBusinessDay(DateTime $date) {
        if (in_array((int)$date->format('N'), $this->nonBusinessDays)) {
            return false; //Date is a nonBusinessDay.
        }
        foreach ($this->holidays as $day) {
            if ($date->format('Y-m-d') == $day->format('Y-m-d')) {
                return false; //Date is a holiday.
            }
        }
        return true; //Date is a business day.
    }
}
```

***UPDATE 1:***
I updated the structure of the $data array to

[image]

and the loop to:

```
for ($i=$minDate; $i <= $maxDate; $i++) {
        $day = getBusinessDay(new DateTime($start_date), $holidays, $i);
        if (array_key_exists($day, $data)) {
            $search_results[]=array($i, $data[$day]);
        }
}
```

The times improved only slightly:

[image]

Is array_key_exists the cause of the delay?

***UPDATE 2:***
This is the $holidays array (It's static, always the same):

[image]

Comment: Is the date column unique in your data ?

Comment: Yes, the same date does not appear twice in the $data array.

Comment: array_filter will probably be faster

Comment: [Profiling PHP Scripts](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). You can use KCacheGrind on *nix, or WinCacheGrind on Windows, to read the profiling file.

Comment: Change `$i++` to `++$i`, this would reduce the time a little.

Comment: Have you tried  timing the routine without array search? i.e. How expensive is the _BusinessDaysCalculator_?

Comment: You are right @RyanVincent . The BusinessDaysCalculator takes about 0.0110 to find the next business day and it goes through the holiday array every single time. Trying to find a way to do this more efficiently.

Comment: Do you need to create the 'BusinessDaysCalculator' every time? Would it be possible to create it once and re-use it? Or only re-create it if the dates change?  Also, it may be worth changing the 'in_array' lookup to a 'key' access in the 'isBusinessDay' function. just guesses on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoring to your comment, the date column contains unique values.
Since you're only filtering on the date column, it's a lot more efficient to index the array via the date column, so you should restructure your data like this:

```
$data = array(
    '2015-02-19' => 1.35625,
    '2015-02-20' => 1.4015,
    '2015-02-23' => 0.9095,
    '2015-02-24' => 1.0635,
    '2015-02-25' => 1.08775,
    '2015-02-26' => 0.947,
    /* ... */
)
```

[`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) needs to loop through the whole array an element corresponding to one date, which can be slow for large arrays.
Using this structure, you can get the data immediately by accessing the data with `$data[$date]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @benoit . The times improved but slightly( 1/2 second). Do you think the array_key_exists (see update in original post) is slowing it down again?

Comment: On my computer the loop takes no more than 0.1 seconds, and this time isn't dependent on the array size (I tried it with one million elements).
Can you post sample data for the `$holidays` variable? My test was done using an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please see update 2 in the original post for the $holidays array. Do you think I should have the dates as strings instead of objects?

Comment: If I set the value of `$holidays` to an array of 100 DateTime objects, the loop doesn't take 0.1 seconds anymore, but 3 seconds. Using strings instead of objects will help.